# HTML5 Canvas slider

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, slider

Trying to create a slider class that lets you easily and quickly customize values. You can drag the handle or click on any part of the slider to move the handle there, and it works... sort of. You can click as many times as you want, but... if you even click once or if you drag, then let go and try again, it only goes down (never up) a tiny bit. That probably sounds confusing, so here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/obo3m38f/9/).

```
var Slider = createEntity({
  init: function (args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.x = args.x || 0;
    this.y = args.y || 0;
    this.width = args.width || 10;
    this.height = args.height || 100;
    this.min = args.min || 0;
    this.max = args.max || 100;
    this.value = args.value || 50;
    this.rotation = args.rotation || 0;
    this.on = args.on || function () {};
    var backFill = randHsla();
    args.back = args.back || {};
    this.back = args.back;
    args.back.fill = args.back.fill || backFill;
    this.back.fill = args.back.fill;
    args.back.borderFill = args.back.borderFill || backFill;
    this.back.borderFill = args.back.borderFill;
    args.back.width = args.back.width || 5;
    this.back.width = args.back.width;
    args.back.x = args.back.x || this.width / 2 - this.back.width / 2;
    this.back.x = args.back.x;
    var handleColor = randHsla();
    args.handle = args.handle || {};
    this.handle = args.handle;
    args.handle.fill = args.handle.fill || handleColor;
    this.handle.fill = args.handle.fill;
    args.handle.borderStroke = args.handle.borderStroke || handleColor;
    this.handle.borderStroke = args.handle.borderStroke;
    args.handle.height = args.handle.height || 5;
    this.handle.height = args.handle.height;
    args.handle.y = args.handle.y || 0;
    this.handle.y = args.handle.y;
    this.updatePos();
  },
  draw: function (fx) {
    fx.save();
    fx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    fx.rotate(this.rotation);
    fx.fillStyle = this.back.fill;
    fx.beginPath();
    fx.fillRect(this.back.x, 0, this.back.width, this.height);
    fx.closePath();
    fx.fillStyle = this.handle.fill;
    fx.strokeStyle = this.handle.borderStroke;
    fx.beginPath();
    fx.rect(0, this.handle.y, this.width, this.handle.height);
    fx.closePath();
    fx.fill();
    fx.stroke();
    fx.restore();
  },
  updateVal: function () {
    var oldVal = this.value,
      handleRange = this.height - this.handle.height,
      valRange = this.max - this.min;
    this.value = (handleRange - this.handle.y) / handleRange * valRange + this.min;
    if (this.on instanceof Function && this.value !== oldVal) {
      this.on();
    }
    return this;
  },
  updatePos: function () {
    var handleRange = this.height - this.handle.height,
      valRange = this.max - this.min;
    this.handle.y = handleRange - ((this.value - this.min) / valRange) * handleRange;
    return this;
  },
  getMouse: function (map) {
    var self = this,
      mouse = getMouse(map),
      bounds = {};
    setBounds();
    map.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
      if (hasPoint(bounds, mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
        map.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        map.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
      } else if (hasPoint(self, mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
        var y = mouse.y - self.y;
        self.handle.y = Math.min(self.height - self.handle.height, Math.max(y, 0));
        self.updateVal();
      }
    });

    function onMouseUp(event) {
      map.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
      map.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      var y = mouse.y - self.y;
      self.handle.y = Math.min(self.height - self.handle.height, Math.max(y, 0));
      self.updateVal();
    }

    function setBounds() {
      bounds.x = self.x;
      bounds.y = self.y + self.handle.y;
      bounds.width = self.width;
      bounds.height = self.handle.height;
    }
    return this;
  }
});
```

External functions such as `createEntity` and `hasPoint` can be found [here](https://github.com/khanfusiion3/Physics/blob/master/utils.js).

How would I make it work after clicking the slider and letting go after the first?

Comment: your fiddle works perfectly on FF, Ubuntu 13. not able to reproduce.

Comment: stating which browser you're having the issue in might help.

Comment: Chromium, Ubuntu 15. Doesn't work for me on Firefox either.

Comment: yea it stopped working when i switched tabs and switched back

Comment: Interesting. It's worked about 4 times total for me but failed the rest. Results seem inconsistent. Not sure what's causing this. Also fails on Opera.

Comment: *Totally an aside*, but in your `draw` method you're using both `fillRect` and `rect`. Note that `fillRect` does not need `closePath` (the fillRect snippet automatically does that for you). But `rect` is a path command so you need `closepath` there.

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listeners if the user clicks on the handle as well, to enable dragging.

```
map.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (hasPoint(bounds, mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
    map.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    map.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  } else if (hasPoint(self, mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
    map.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    map.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    var y = mouse.y - self.y;
    self.handle.y = Math.min(self.height - self.handle.height, Math.max(y, 0));
    self.updateVal();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but why constantly add and remove event listeners? Constant add/remove caused your glitch, but also it's not very efficient?  Perhaps a more efficient pattern is to aggregate the slider plus other canvas mouse handlers into single mouse handling functions and always keep them active. Eg canvas.on('mousedown'...) will hit-test the slider thumb, but also does non-slider mousedown handling. Then when the slider is active you can have the slider handler code triggered and when the slider is inactive you can bypass the slider handler code.